# Jquery Tokenize plugin with activeadmin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm trying the jquery Tokenize plugin for multi select options,I added the files to assets/javascripts and assets/stylesheet folders, 
Called those filesin  application.js

```
      //= require jquery
      //= require jquery_ujs
      //= require jquery.tokenize
      //= require_tree .
```

I'm using activeadmin and I invoke the file in active_admin.js also but it's not working, I need help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding the below code in config/initializers/active_admin.rb file.

```
config.register_javascript '/your/path/jquery.tokenize.js'
```

Also you need to initialise Tokenize. For this you can create a new file new_file.js and add the below code and include this file into active_admin.rb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tokenize').tokenize();
)};
```

New config/initializers/active_admin.rb file content will be like

```
config.register_javascript '/your/path/jquery.tokenize.js'
config.register_javascript '/your/path/new_file.js'
```